# How to pass a function between PHP files

Tags: php, function, joomla3.0

Hopefully simple problem to solve. I have the main file which has a function in, this file then includes another file. Within this second file is the call to the function. However I get the error below.

Main File:

```
function sample() {
  echo "hello world";
}
```

Secondary file called by the main file

```
sample();
```

Error given

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sample() in [path hidden].php on line 20
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you post the complete files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the file with the function in it to the page that will be running it.

see [PHP Include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for more information.

example:
functions.php

```
<?php
    // Echo Hello World to browser //
    function sample() {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
    // Include the file with function //
    include 'functions.php';

    // Use Function //
    sample();

?>
```

Comment: are you sure you're using the correct path to the functions file?

Comment: Yes, the file definately loads correctly as I am also getting it to echo "hello world!"

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps calling the function sample() more than once, possibly once before the file with the function is included?  The error message should tell you which line of which file is generating the error.